# I cannot split in a different columns the dictionary inside the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JyvM.png)

Inside of the dataframe there are dictionary type values,What I want to do is take this values and added as new columns, However when I try to extract the values it pop ups an error

df= pd.DataFrame.to_dict(data_raw_df["belongs_to_collection"])

I called the dataframe as data_raw_df

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO9z3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired output using `.apply()` because `to_dict()` is converting the whole dataframe therefore you are facing an error but if you use `apply()` along with lambda your issue will be resolved.

For Example:

```
df["column_1"] = data_raw_df["belongs_to_collection"].apply(lambda x: x.get("value1") if isinstance(x, dict) else None)
```